# Google Chrome Dev Tools keeps popping up on refresh

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools

On every page refresh in Google Chrome, the Dev Tools keeps popping up. I have to manually press Esc each time. Also, I have already tried the settings suggested by some of the other people like below, but that has not helped;

```
Uncheck "Enable JavaScript source maps"
Uncheck "Enable CSS source maps"
```

I have version 90.x

Please suggest.

Comment: Under Dev Tools > Preferences > Global, do you have `Auto-open DevTools for popups` ticked?

Comment: yes..just verified...that option is unchecked as well....